# How to access both server and ILO with a single link?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ilo

I have a server in a datacenter that offer 1 link, one interface IP and several logical IPs. The server is currently running on XEN with the physical IP on the main interface and other IPs assigned to VPS.

The server has a second ILO port (currently not used) that I want to connect through the standard link. Using a 2 ports switch is not a solution because I have two interfaces and the provider only offer 1 interface IP (I don't really understand what is the purpose of the interface IP except that it should not be normally used to access the server and it is not on the same subnet that the other IPs).

What solution can I use to access both the ILO port and the server with one link ?

My idea is to consume one IPv6 (I have plenty of them) for ILO and connect both the server and the ILO port using a 2 ports switch. Is that possible?

Comment: Which EXACT model of server have you got - that defines what version of iLO you have, recent versions allow you to share iLO functionality over 'server ports' but it does depend on the model.

Comment: HPE ProLiant DL120 Gen9 Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the update, you've got iLO version 4, which does indeed allow you to do what you want. You need to go into your iLO settings and select the 'Network' tab on the left, then select 'Shared Network Port' and 'General' - make your settings and you're away! You may need to restart iLO for these changes to take effect.